# This is a question about decrypting the password received from PHP with MySQL's des_decrypt

Tags: php, mysql

[mysql]

```
create table test (
user_id varchar(100),
password varchar(50));
```

After creating the table

```
insert into test (user_id,password) values ('Jace',HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('Jace123','test')));
```

Cryptographic row insertion

[php]

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test123', 'test');
$sql = "SELECT user_id,AES_DECRYPT(PASSWORD),'test') AS PASSWORD from test";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$hash = password_hash('Jace123',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if ($row['PASSWORD'] == $hash) {
    echo "right";
}else{
    echo "wrong";
?>
```

The answer is, of course, wrong. I want to match the password encrypted in mysql in php, but I'm curious about what algorithm I should use. That said, I'd like to hear the right answer. Do you have any feedback?

Comment: Note that the password is hashed, not encrypted. They are different processes - a hash is not reversible.

Comment: I think explicit passwords should not be displayed in the DB. Also, I think entering the decryption key in php might be a problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: There isn't a decryption key because the password isn't encrypted, it's hashed. Please learn the difference. And read the duplicate in the blue box above to learn how to check the validity of a password against the hashed copy

Comment: Here's an old SO post about the difference between hashing and encryption: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms This is indeed an important distinction that you need to know if you are going to be a programmer implementing authentication systems.

Comment: Oh thank you for sharing great material.